# Getting System.InvalidCastException on ExpandableListView

Tags: c#, xamarin

I'm using visual studio 2015 with the extension Xamarin in order to make an app. I got an error (System.InvalidCastException) when I try to cast into ExpandableListView.

```
using Android.App;
using Android.Widget;
using Android.OS;
using Android.Runtime;
using Android.Content;
using Android.Views;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Graphics;
using static Android.Widget.ListView;
using static Android.Widget.ExpandableListView;

namespace SecondApp
{
    [Activity(Label = "SecondApp", MainLauncher = true, Icon = "@drawable/icon", Theme = "@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light")]
    public class MainActivity : Activity
    {
    ExpandableListView expandableListView;
    ListView listView;


    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
    {
        base.OnCreate(bundle);
        SetContentView(Resource.Layout.Main);


        expandableListView = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.SavedAnimationsList);
        listView = FindViewById<ListView>(Resource.Id.animation);

     }
}
```

I hope you guys can help!

Thanks.

Comment: I'm getting the error right here : `expandableListView = FindViewById<ExpandableListView>(Resource.Id.SavedAnimationsList);`

Comment: Why did you delete and repost?  There doesn't appear to be any new information here that was not in your previous post.  Have you tried to use the debugger to verify what type is returned by the first FindViewByID?  Are you sure that SavedAnimationsList is an ExpandableListView?

Comment: FindViewById returns Android.Views.View as a type. I can't cast it into ExpandableListView. Yes, SavedAnimationsList is an ExpandableView. I have the exact same code on another PC and it works.